# How to Resolve Server Error in '/' Application (Configuration Error)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, web-config

My web application was working perfectly minutes ago now I get this error when I run it.

How can I solve this issue since its not even part of my project files?

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE)) (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config line 285)
>
> Line 285: add name="ErrorHandlerModule" type="System.Web.Mobile.ErrorHandlerModule, System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"**

[image]

Comment: Please copy the error messages here, it's almost impossible to read in your picture.

Comment: Apparently something has changed during these minutes. What was that?

Comment: configuration files don't change by itself...what did you do between "it was working perfectly" and the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I probably should have done this before posting the question.

I saved my work then restarted Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me as well after restarting visual studio.